# Site only refreshes when adding www. to URL

Tags: http, refresh

First time posting so please bear with me.
I'm the unofficial web guy at the company I work for and I helped create our basic static HTML site.
Any work that I do to the site offline and then FTP shows up instantly on my machine. I rarely, if ever, need to clear the cache for changes to show up. However, within the company I work for, nearly half of the users never see the updates. Some do, some don't. 
On the machines that don't I've cleared the cache in browser and through the internet control panel settings. Nothing. Still shows the stale content. The only thing that works - and I've seen this both in Chrome and IE is that when I add www in front of the URL is then shows the refreshed site. No big deal, right? Well for users who type in mysite.com without the  in front will not see the updates. People who have favorited it like that, will not see the updates.

Now, on to what I've tried to fix it. After much research many people have steered me away from meta tag refresh so I haven't tried that, however, with the help of the IT guy we have, from what we can tell, set the HTTP header of the site to always refresh. This did not do anything for us. 
I've tried changing image names in the HTML page when updating a photo and that didn't work either. 
I haven't been able to find a .htaccess file so can I create one? If we (IT guy and I) changed the HTTP Header setting to always refresh but there is not .htaccess file will there be no change?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I have searched on here for the answer and the two most suggested changes are HTTP Header and Meta refresh. HTTP header didn't help and it seems the Meta tag route is bad form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a DNS issue. You need to ask the provider of your web services to add an A or a CNAME record for the domain's root.

If you don't understand the above, just call the provider of your web presence (the company that hosts your web server) and tell them you want yourdomain.com and www.yourdomain.com to go to the same place.

Comment: Hey Metaphor, thank for the quick reply. Talked to the IT guy and he is going to look into it. He thinks that's a very good possibility and that it may be an in house issue since we are all on the same network here. Going to reach out to more outside users to see if they are having the same issue.